# Como puedo arreglar un error del Velocity?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-tool-suite

Tengo que subir un proyecto a producción donde localmente funciona al 100% pero al montarlo al servidor sale este error en el log:

```
    2016-11-14 07:26:44,465 INFO
    [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource]  
    - Theme created: name 'theme', basename [theme]
     2016-11-14 07:26:44,469 INFO   
    [org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils] - Found JSP 
     2.0 ExpressionEvaluator
    2016-11-14 07:26:44,469 INFO  
    [org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils] - Found 
    Jakarta JSTL ExpressionEvaluatorManager
    Hibernate: select usuario0_.IDUS as IDUS1_8_, usuario0_.IDPA as
    IDPA4_8_, usuario0_.ROUS as ROUS2_8_, usuario0_.NAUS as NAUS3_8_ from 
    Usuarios usuario0_ where usuario0_.NAUS=?
    Hibernate: select participan0_.IDPA as IDPA1_4_0_, participan0_.CEPA 
    as CEPA2_4_0_, participan0_.CORREOPA as CORREOPA3_4_0_, 
    participan0_.NOEM as NOEM4_4_0_, participan0_.NOPA as NOPA5_4_0_, 
    participan0_.TPPA as TPPA6_4_0_ from Participantes participan0_ where 
    participan0_.IDPA=?
    2016-11-14 07:26:46,676 ERROR   
    [net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer] - Error 
    initializing Velocity: java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
   at net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer.displayComponents(VelocityMenuDisplayer.java:105)
    at net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer.display(VelocityMenuDisplayer.java:87)
    at net.sf.navigator.taglib.DisplayMenuTag.doStartTag(DisplayMenuTag.java:100)
    at net.sf.navigator.taglib.el.DisplayMenuTag.doStartTag(DisplayMenuTag.java:45)
    at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_menu_005fdisplayMenu_005f0(menu_jsp.java:153)
    at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_menu_005fuseMenuDisplayer_005f0(menu_jsp.java:112)
   at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:73)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
   at org.apache.jsp.decorators.grupoICE_jsp._jspService(grupoICE_jsp.java:204)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.OldDecorator2NewDecorator.render(OldDecorator2NewDecorator.java:46)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:33)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)   
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error initializing Velocity: 
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer.displayComponents(VelocityMenuDisplayer.java:109)
   at net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer.display(VelocityMenuDisplayer.java:87)
   at net.sf.navigator.taglib.DisplayMenuTag.doStartTag(DisplayMenuTag.java:100)
   at net.sf.navigator.taglib.el.DisplayMenuTag.doStartTag(DisplayMenuTag.java:45)
    at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_menu_005fdisplayMenu_005f0(menu_jsp.java:153)
    at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_menu_005fuseMenuDisplayer_005f0(menu_jsp.java:112)
   at org.apache.jsp.includes.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:73)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
  at org.apache.jsp.decorators.grupoICE_jsp._jspService(grupoICE_jsp.java:204)
   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.compatability.OldDecorator2NewDecorator.render(OldDecorator2NewDecorator.java:46)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:33)
   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
   at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
   at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
   at net.sf.navigator.displayer.VelocityMenuDisplayer.displayComponents(VelocityMenuDisplayer.java:105)
    ... 49 more
```

y este es mi Velocity Properties

```
    # Prevent velocity.log from getting written to current directory
    # http://issues.appfuse.org/browse/APF-597
       runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute
    runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category=org.apache.velocity
    # Prevent ResourceNotFoundException with Velocity 1.7
    velocimacro.library = net/sf/navigator/displayer/globalMacros.vm
    velocimacro.library.autoreload = true
```

y mi velocity log

```
    2016-08-18 10:47:11,670 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use  
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 10:47:40,221 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 11:19:16,112 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 11:22:20,615 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 11:25:49,504 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 14:07:25,228 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 14:13:32,939 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-18 14:22:21,049 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use  
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-22 08:08:13,076 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-22 08:09:57,475 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-22 08:17:02,472 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
    2016-08-22 08:32:00,773 - WebappLoader is deprecated. Use 
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader instead.
```

*Para que entienda un poco mejor el problema les dejare las imagenes de lo que sucede.*

*Este es el sistema corriendo desde el servidor*
[image: Este es el sistema corriendo localmente]

*Este es el sistema corriendo desde el servidor*
[image: Este es el sistema corriendo en el servidor]

Comment: Estas usando la misma versión de velocity en producción y en tu ambiente de pruebas, además de eso no estas en un Hell Jar? (jar dupĺicados en diferente versión)

Comment: @Ajeno al parecer en el ambiente de pruebas y en producción se maneja la misma versión.. y todavia no he podido solucionar ese problema ya que al quitar el velocity todo el header desaparece

Comment: De casualidad tu servidor está en windows?

Comment: no, se encuentra en ubuntu

Comment: Todo parece indicar que el error es por que no estas colocando un nombre en el método getTemplate por lo que llega null y sale el null pointer no te hará falta un archivo properties de tu aplicación?. 
 public Template getTemplate(String name)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException, ParseErrorException
    {
        return ri.getTemplate( name );
    }

Comment: @Ajeno pero si ese fuese el caso, no tendría que dar el mismo problema localmente?

Comment: En veces en desarrollo dejamos cosas que pasamos por obvias, sin afan de ofender, utilizas maven o como construyes tu war? llegas a usar un properties?

Comment: si entiendo, y no ofendes, si utilizo maven y para construir el war lo que hago es exportarlo como war.